# isc-dhcp-server can't start

Tags: dhcpd

i installed dhcp3-server , now i want to start its service and it said :
`[FAIL] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
 failed!`
i check ps aux | grep dhcp  shows :

`root      6178  0.0  0.0   9956  3708 ?        S    23:06   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -4 -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action -pf /var/run/dhclient-wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient-eee3fc61-32c1-4aa7-b189-94556369eac2-wlan0.lease -cf /var/run/nm-dhclient-wlan0.conf wlan0
root      6418  0.0  0.0   7764   860 pts/0    R+   23:13   0:00 grep dhcp`

`dhcpd.conft`  is like default , before that i tried to implement a dhcp server on my at0 
but i couldn't . 
if need a details just said . 
`i tried to remove it but :

`[FAIL] Stopping ISC DHCP server: dhcpd failed!`

i don know what can i do now ?!
how can i fix it ? or delete it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the file `/var/log/syslog` show? That's where the diagnostic information will be.

If I had to guess, I'd say you don't have a static IP address configured for your interface that you have dhcpd set to run on. You need to add one in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: i config static ip to my at0 ; and this is the last ten line of syslog : ` No subnet declaration for wlan0 (192.168.1.3).
Jun 25 23:21:20 bahram dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is not what
Jun 25 23:21:20 bahram dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Jun 25 23:21:20 bahram dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Jun 25 23:21:20 bahram dhcpd:    to which interface wlan0 is attached. ** ` i think you right ; i clean my dhcp and my at0 and tried to start service dhcpd maybe you right, tnq

Comment: You need to configure a static IP for the wlan0 in `/etc/network/interfaces`